# 3D array assigning values

Tags: java, arrays, dimension

Can I use the following format to simplify assigning values in java to a 3D array if possible then how?

```
    int [][][]array = new int[3][][];

    array[0] = new int [4][5];
    array[1] = new int [5][5];
    array[2] = new int [3][5];


    array[0] = {{1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5}};
    array[1] = {{1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,4,5}};
    array[2] = {{1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
int[][][] array = {
        {{1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5}},
        {{1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,4,5}},
        {{1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5}},
};
```

Another alternative:

```
int[][] array1 = {{1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5}};
int[][] array2 = {{1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2,3,4,5}};
int[][] array3 = {{1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5} , {1,2,3,4,5}};
int[][][] array = {array1, array2, array3};
```

The initializer expression `{...}` can only be used at declaration time.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and cleanest way to assign this type of data -- put the data into a file, here a text file would be adequate, and then read it in using nested for loops. This avoids hard-coding the data, and makes it easy to change the data without having to change the code.

Comment: Not with the lengths coded into the program and a flat list of integers on the data file. To remain truly flexible, some sort of meta-notation for delimiting elements at each level is indicated. Might end up with s.th. like the 1st literal shown in janos' answer.